# Single linked list implementation in a single class

Tags: java

I have the following code,but i don understand the line w.next=nextnode;
What it means?
Does my code seems to be complicated or is there an easiest way to implement this
Any suggestions or ideas?

```
class Node1{
    private String data;
    private Node1 nextNode=null;
    private Node1 lastnode=null;
    private Node1 next=null;
    public Node1()
     {

     }
     public Node1(String r)
     {
       data=r;  
     }
     public void displayitems()
     {
         System.out.println(data);
     }
    public void insert(String data){

     Node1 w=new Node1(data);
     if(w==null)
     {
        lastnode=w;
}
else
{
 w.next=nextNode;
 nextNode=w;
}
     }   
    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Items in list");
        Node1 current=nextNode;
      current.displayitems();
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){
      Node1 a=new Node1();
      a.insert("deepak");
      a.insert("deep");
      a.display();


        }
    }
```

Comment: How did you "have" the code? Why don't you write it by yourself?

Comment: It's a sample code...i want to know what's happening ...they call me beginner to java understood JB

Comment: It is not a good example. There are several problems with it.

Comment: This code is crappy, and if it's sample code, then it's a very bad sample to show to any beginner developer. You'd better forget about it, and rewrite everything from scratch.

Comment: is there something wrong with a java.util.List implementation?

Comment: Java is object Oriented language, we break our problems as much as we can. So there isn't any sense in doing everything in one class. I would suggest try to play with it, go for generics, do some complex task like Sorting, Searching, Randomize. That will help you learn the concepts.

Comment: if you want to understand linked list, go took at the wikipedia page on it, there are diagrams and sample code. this is not a good representation of linked list implementation

Comment: Not quite relevant.. but `if(w==null)` is kind of over cautious. Constructors never return null.

Comment: hd1..there'snothing wrong but my TL is asking me to try implementing it

Comment: Rp is it right to go for isempty()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it's good that you try to implement some data structure of your own. But if you need to implement such thing, you need to do an in-depth analysis of how that data structure (Singly LinkedList in your case) stores and retrieves data & whether order of insertion is maintained or it maintains sorted order and so.

> Suggesting you some points to follow always before doing an
>   implementation.
>
> 1. Understand the concept first.
> 2. Write down the algorithm about how it works.
> 3. Design it (probably writing down the design on a paper is best practice & will give you a clear view on what you implement)
> 4. Implement & test it.

In your case here, you design a Node class for your linkedlist which would take care of all node related tasks like storing next/previous node address (SinglyLinkedList would store only next node address). Keep this Node as [Inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) (is best practice) of your LinkedList class.

```
private class Node<T>{
        private Node<T> next;
        private T data;

        public Node(T data, Node<T> next){
            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
```

I have used [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) here. You can do it without using Generics too. Implement linkedlist operations (like add/remove etc) in your linkedlist class traversing through these Node objects. Whatever algorithm you have written down helps you in such places to implement in a efficient manner.

I have my sample code here. Whatever code you posted here is not a good implementation. Try following the steps I specified & you will have your better code.

```
public class LinkedList<T> {

    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> nextNode;
    private int size = 0;

    public void addFirst(T element){
        head = new Node<T>(element, head);
    }

    public void add(T element){
        if(head == null)
            addFirst(element);
        else{
            Node<T> node = head;
            while(node.next != null){
                node = node.next;
            }
            node.next = new Node<T>(element, null);
        }
        size++;
    }

    public int size(){
        return size;
    }

// Inner class somewhere here
}
```

This is simple representation. You can implement Iterable & Iterator interfaces to loop through the list.

Comment: Clear Explanation,,thank u svjn

Comment: But there is no main method in the code

Comment: Why do you need a main method in this class. Have a separate class with main method and make use of this LinkedList class.